# Python 3 import error _Py_set_inheritable_async_safe

Tags: linux, python-3.6

/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload/_posixsubprocess.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _Py_set_inheritable_async_safe

after installing the python3-idle on my opensuse , this message will appear when I try to import something

Answer (score 0):

If this happens when importing or using a third-party package, simply uninstall and reinstall the third-party package in question. This fixed it for me. If you don't know which third-party package is relevant, uninstall and reinstall them all.

The problem is evidently not with `subprocess` or `_posixsubprocess`.